make authenticated and login work for multiple table other then auth User table django?
I have created hostTable model in hostlogin app and I want to use this table for login purpose for that i have created custom authenticate function because default authenticate() was working for auth user table only. Also login() is not attaching current session to the users from hostTable. Although it working fine if I set AUTH_USER_MODEL ='hostlogin.HostTable' but then admin page is not working also this is not acceptable solution because hostTable I will use for teaches login (127.0.0.1:8081/tlogin/) and studentlogin table I will use for student login (127.0.0.1:8081/slogin/) that time how will I use two different table for different login() and authenticate ().
models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser,AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password


class HostTable(AbstractBaseUser):
    pid=models.AutoField(primary_key=True,auto_created=True)
    username=models.CharField(max_length=50,unique=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    #...someotherfields...
    createdtime =models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    last_login=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_authenticated=models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS=['hostname','ownername','password']
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.password = make_password(self.password)
        super(HostTable, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hostname
    


view.py

def hostlogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            print('view',username,password)
            user = hostTableAuth.authenticate(request,username,password)
            print('view',user)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                messages.success(request, f' welcome {username} !!')
                # print(request.META['REMOTE_USER'])
                print('r',request.user)
                print('r',request.user.is_authenticated)
                print('s',request.session)
                request.session['username']=username
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.info(request, f'account done not exit plz sign in')
    form = UserLoginForm()
    return render(request, 'hostlogin/login.html', {'form':form, 'title':'log in'})


customeAuth.py
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend,ModelBackend
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password
from .models import HostTable


class hostTableAuth(ModelBackend):
      def authenticate(self, request,username, password):
        user=HostTable.objects.filter(username=username).first()
        print('user',username,password,user.password)
        if user is not None:
            login_valid = user.username == username
            pwd_valid = check_password(password, user.password)
            print(login_valid,pwd_valid)
            if login_valid and pwd_valid:
                try:
                    user = HostTable.objects.get(username=username)
                except HostTable.DoesNotExist:
                    # Create a new user. There's no need to set a password
                    # because only the password from settings.py is checked.
                    user = HostTable(username=username)
                    user.is_staff = True
                    user.is_superuser = True
                    user.save()
                print('auth1',user)
                return user
        else:
            print('auth2',user)

            return None

      def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return HostTable.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except HostTable.DoesNotExist:
            return None



Why you wanna add another table for Authentication ? I don't understand. Can you be clear on why you wanna do taht?

I want to keep teachers and student login table separate with some more specifics column to each table then the basics columns in auth user table. @Sooshiance

well there is no need to do that. In Django there are two models : "BaseUserManager" and "AbstractBaseUser". You can define them in your user app and in the "AbstractBaseUser" you can add a field named "role". This field is a Positive integer field and holds two value 1, 2 ...  1 for Teacher and 2 for Student. When a user go to register page he will choose his type. So in your login process it will recognize them as well. so simple. no need to add another table bro.....

Do you need the code? I can provide you.

yes sure code will be helpful. @Sooshiance

Probably you might need to distinguish the Customer from Vendor right? If you are, I can  create their own dashboard based on their "role". send me a comment if you need.

Thanks for that but with the help of provided you code I made that already .@Sooshiance

Your models are like :
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager


class Role:
    Vendor = 1
    Customer = 2

    ROLE = (
        ('Vendor', Vendor),
        ('Customer',Customer),)


class AllUser(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, phone, email, username, full_name, password=None, **kwargs):
        
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('need Email')
        
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('need Username')
        
        if not phone:
            raise ValueError('need Phone number')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            phone=phone,
            full_name=full_name,
            **kwargs,
        )
        user.is_active = False
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staff(self, phone, email, username, full_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            phone=phone,
            full_name=full_name,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_active  = False
        user.is_superuser = False        
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, phone, email, username, full_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            phone=phone,
            full_name=full_name,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_staff     = True
        user.is_active    = True
        user.is_superuser = True  
        user.is_admin     = True      
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    numbers      = RegexValidator(r'^[0-9a]*$', message='only numbers')
    phone        = models.CharField(max_length=11, unique=True)
    email        = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username     = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    full_name    = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    role         = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=Role.ROLE, default=1)
    is_active    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff     = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
    is_admin     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_login   = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_at   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = "phone"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email", "username", "full_name"]
    
    objects = AllUser()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.phone
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'User'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Users'

forms.py :
from .models import User


class RegisterUser(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['phone', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name']
        labels = {
            'password': 'Password',
        }
        widgets = {
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control my-5', 'placeholder':'example1234@gmail.com'}),
            'phone': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control my-5', 'placeholder':'09123456789'}),
            'username': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control my-5', 'placeholder':'Username'}),
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control my-5', 'placeholder':'••••••••••••'}),
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control my-5', 'placeholder':'Ali'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control my-5', 'placeholder':'alizadeh'}),
            'role': forms.ChoiceWidget(attrs={'class':'form-control my-5'}),
        }

views.py :
def loginUser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request, 'شما نمیتوانید به این صفحه مراجعه کنید')
        return redirect('HOME')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        
        user = auth.authenticate(request, phone=phone, password=password)
        
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, 'خوش آمدید')
            return redirect('PROFILE')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'مشخصات وارد شده اشتباه می باشد، دوباره تلاش کنید')
            return render(request, 'user/login.html')
    return render(request, "user/login.html")

def registerUser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request, 'شما نمیتوانید به این صفحه مراجعه کنید')
        return redirect('HOME')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterUser(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            role = forms.cleaned_data['role']
            user = User.objects.create_user(email=email, username=username, password=password,first_name=first_name,role=role,
                                            last_name=last_name, phone=phone)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'اطلاعات شما با موفقیت ثبت گردید')
            return redirect('HOME')
        else:
            messages.error(request, f'{form.errors}')
            return redirect('REGISTER')
    else:
        form = RegisterUser()
    return render(request, "user/signup.html", {'form': form})

sorry, cuase of I'm persian(Iranian) ... you see messages are typed in persian words :). You can change them as you please
